# Merge two objects using underscore or plain javascript

Tags: javascript, merge, underscore.js

I have a difficult to merge two objects from javascript, i use underscore and tried many attempts, googled but i cannot achieve my aim, please see below the two objects :

```
// Obj A
   [{  
      "activite":"Danser le rock",
      "categorie":"Activités physiques",
      "selected":true
   },
   {  
      "activite":"Danses latino",
      "categorie":"Activités physiques",
      "selected":true
   }]

// Obj B
  [{  
    "activite":"Danser le rock",
    "categorie":"Activités physiques",
  },
  {  
        "activite":"Danses latino",
        "categorie":"Activités physiques",
  }, 
  {  
      "categorie":"Activités physiques",
      "activite":"Danses latino"
 }]
```

Here is one attempt

```
function updateCentres(obj1, obj2) {
   for (var p in obj2) {
      if (obj1[p]) {
         _.extend(obj1[p], obj2[p]);
      } else {
       obj1[p] = obj2[p];
      }
  }
}
updateCentres(objA, objB) //<== outputs undefined
```

Here i have to update objB from objA, as a fact of matter i want to inject selected:true to correspondant piece, could someone helps me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does "merge" mean here? You've got two arrays. Do you want to concatenate the arrays? Something else?

Comment: `objB = objA` maybe?

Comment: Will the arrays always have the entries in the same order? (That is, Obj A has "Danser le rock" first, and so does Obj B; is that reliable?)

Comment: @JonasWilms no, i have to update objB, this means keep others pieces and update correspondant piece

Comment: @T.J.Crowder,  A and B is not in the same order

Comment: @ikalangita but your merging code assumes that they are in the same order?

Comment: @JonasWilms, whatever the order is i have to merge A and B, i have tested with objA.concat(objB); like this http://jsfiddle.net/kqvcyp90/10661/#&togetherjs=HzIFUF5sCE but seems contents is duplicated.

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher - Don't think so, this is updating arrays of objects, relating them by a property, not updating non-array objects.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it doesn't work correctly if `ObjB` has duplicate `activite` values (as is the case in the question, "Danses latino" is duplicated).

Answer (score 1):

Actually your objects are arrays which you can easily iterate with `for .. of`. Now you could map every activite to a selected property by going over `objA` (bad name, just saying) then you can go over `objB` and add that selected property:

```
  const isSelected = new Map();

  for(const { activite, selected } of objA)
   isSelected.set(activite, selected);

  for(const event of objB)
    event.selected = isSelected.get(event.activite);
```

Comment: If it's just setting the `selected` property, this is a good way to do it.